# How to set margin around ImageCell in Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I want to have some space around the Image cell items of a ListView:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" HasUnevenRows="True">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding Image}" TextColor="Black" DetailColor="Gray"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackLayout>
```

but there's no Margin property available for the `ImageCell`?

**EDIT**

I did what cvanbeek suggested before posting the question:

```
<DataTemplate>
   <StackLayout Padding="5">
       <ImageCell Text="{Binding Title}" ImageSource="{Binding Image}" TextColor="Black" DetailColor="Gray"/>
   </StackLayout>
</DataTemplate>
```

but I got this exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.

in the `OnCreate` method in MainActivity.cs

Comment: You could surround it with a `StackLayout` with Padding

Comment: not possible, see the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[DataTemplate definition](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplate/)

Only `View` can be put inside `DataTemplate`, however `StackLayout` is `Layout`.

Use a ViewCell instead , it is more flexible and controllable.

```
<ListView >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
                <StackLayout Padding="20" Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    <Label Margin="20" Text="123"/>
                    <Image Source="Assets/StoreLogo.png"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```